# Writing python unit tests inside the actual code

Tags: python, unit-testing

Sometimes I'm writing small utilities functions and pack them as python package.
How small? 30 - 60 lines of python.
And my question is do you think writing the tests inside the actual code is bad? abusing?

I can see a great benefits like usage examples inside the code itself without jumping between files (again from really small projects).
Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Actual code
def increment(number, by=1):
    return number += by

# Tests
def test_increment_positive():
    assert increment(1) == 2

def test_increment_negative():
    assert increment(-5) == -4

def test_increment_zero():
    assert increment(0) == 1
```

The general Idea taken from the monitoring framework riemann which I use, in riemann you write your tests file along with your code [link](http://riemann.io/howto.html#writing-tests)

Answer (score 4):

You can write [`doctests`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html) inside your documentation to indicate how your function should be used:

```
def increment(number, by=1):
    """ Increments the given number by some other number
    >>> increment(3)
    4
    >>> increment(5,3)
    8
    """
    return number += by
```

From the documentation:

> - To check that a module’s docstrings are up-to-date by verifying that all interactive examples still work as documented.
> - To perform regression testing by verifying that interactive examples    from a test file or a test object work as expected.
> - To write tutorial documentation for a package, liberally illustrated    with input-output examples. Depending on whether the
>     examples or the    expository text  are emphasized, this has the
>     flavor of “literate    testing” or “executable documentation”